# Are there any kernel or libc headers that deal with detecting the boot type?

Tags: linux-kernel, glibc, linux-kernel-headers

I am currently reading `/proc/cmdline` to determine a device's boot reason. Currently, I am using Android's [Canonical Boot Reason](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/bootloader/boot-reason) from the bootloader to determine why the device booted. I just read the values for `androidboot.bootreason`, eg

```
androidboot.bootreason=reboot
androidboot.bootreason=bootloader
androidboot.bootreason=PMIC_cold_reboot
```

Is there a Linux Kernel API to do something similar?

Comment: "*Is there a Linux Kernel API to do something similar?*" -- AFAIK, no. The file **/proc/cmdline** does not contain any "*device's boot reason*". Depending on the kernel's build configuration, the command line could be hardcoded and the same text for every boot.  Some SoCs have a *Reset Controller*, which can be interrogated through its driver as to the cause/reason for the startup (e.g. power-on, watchdog reset, software reset, etc.). Also note the kernel typically doesn't know (nor care) which device(s) was/were the boot medium/media.